# What ranged monsters have the highest damage output?

Tags: dnd-4e, monsters

I'm looking for monsters (Heroic Tier) with this feature.
Damage as high (or higher) as a brute's, but ranged.
I need them for a matter of design (I wanna compare them to other monsters to learn what makes them balanced) and also to give a hard time to the Battlerage Vigor Fighter from my group.

Comment: @PurpleMonkey: Putting the edition in the title is ok, even though it's a tag, only if it the question title still organically flows as a proper question. *Forcing* it, on the other hand, is not ok. SE mods comment on this [all](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105991/232761) [the](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/100492/232761) [time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/88992/232761). I realize the author forced the edition into the title, but I thought I'd point this out since your comment was unclear on that.

Answer (score 1):

The Green Arcanian (level 8 artillery, Monster Manual 3, page 16) is one of the most damaging artillery monsters from Heroic Tier. Comparing it to the Hornstone Gargoyle (level 8 brute, Monster Manual 3, page 93), the basic attack damage is almost identical, with the Gargoyle coming ahead with 2 points of static bonus. Also, the Gargoyle has an at-will charge that deals 2d12+5 damage, as well as a grab and ongoing 5 damage.

But the Green Arcanian's Acid Bolt deals 3 points of damage to each enemy adjacent to the original target, and they have an interesting power called Arcane Surge. This Encounter utility causes one of their implement attacks to max out on damage, triggered when they hit.

Finally, the Green Arcanian would actually fight well paired with a couple of Gargoyles, as the Arcanian's Stream of Acid and Orb of Denial would keep an opponent's AC down by 2 points.